# re-declaring a global variable after its definition in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int b;
int b = 5;
int b;

int main() {
   printf("%d\n", b);
   return 0;
}
```

Above compiles and run successfully. Note this is **only doable in global scope**,
doing the same inside `main` will not compile.

Is this because `int b;` is `a declaration and a tentative definition` and Multiple tentative definitions are allowed in C, even if it's done after fully defining it globally?

Comment: I believe its because the compiler simplifies the above code to a singular `int b = 5`, since it recognizes the previous definition is virtually identical to the declaration + assignment in the next line. I could be wrong however.

Comment: You've already answered the question yourself. Yes, they are tentative definitions and you can have as many as you like, within the same translation unit, long as there is no more than one definition with initializer. Also, this sorts under the category "completely useless knowledge"... simply don't write code like this ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declared at file scope, a variable with no initializer and no storage class specifier (i.e. `extern` or `static`) constitutes a *tentative definition*.  There may be any number of these, but at most one "full" definition which includes an initializer.

Section 6.9.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives examples of these as well as others:

> ```
> int i1 = 1;         //definition, external linkage
> static int i2 = 2;  //definition, internal linkage
> extern int i3 = 3;  //definition, external linkage
> int i4;             //tentative definition, external linkage
> static int i5;      //tentative definition, internal linkage
>
> int i1;             //valid tentative definition, refers to previous
> int i2;             //6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
> int i3;             //valid tentative definition, refers to previous
> int i4;             //valid tentative definition, refers to previous
> int i5;             //6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
>
> extern int i1;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i2;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is internal
> extern int i3;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i4;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i5;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is internal
> ```